# Why does MySQL database access require a forward slash in the server url?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've been learning about databases access using Oracle and MySQL and found this interesting difference.

```
 String dbURL1 = "jdbc:oracle:@serverName:port:database";
```

verses

```
 String dbURL1 = "jdbc:mysql://serverName:port:/database";
```

Why the slash? If I don't provide the slash for MySQL, compiler is unable to determine a suitable driver. However, for Oracle, if I do provide a slash, the compiler also produces an error.

Comment: The form and interpretation of a database URL are characteristics of the JDBC driver in use.  Different drivers can and do choose different conventions.

Comment: Most URLs look like that. The real question is why does the Oracle URL look different, and the answer is that the Oracle thing after @ doesn't name a hostname but a configuration file entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL format is defined by the Driver.

For MySQL you can check the full URL format [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The format of connection string in JDBC is not mandated by the standard. Each DB driver is free to decide on its own format, based on the preferences of the designers. Moreover, when multiple drivers exist for the same RDBMS, the format for connection strings to the same database may be different.

According to [the MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), MySQL uses the following format for its connection string:

```
MySQL (MM.MySQL Driver)
jdbc:mysql://<HOST>:<PORT>/<DB>
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
```

Oracle thin client, on the other hand, uses this format:

```
Oracle Thin
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:<PORT>:<SID>
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

As you can see, slash `/` is part of the required syntax for MySql, but it is not part of the syntax for Oracle.

Comment: You shouldn't cite a third party reference when the MySQL reference is online.